# Visual Studio Crashing When Checking In

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, checkin

My Visual Studio 2013 is crashing when I trying to check in my pending changes everytime. How can I solve it?

Crash Log :

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Package 'SccProviderPackage' failed to load.
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(Int32 hr, Int32[] expectedHRFailure)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider.ServiceProviderExtensionMethods.EnsurePackageLoaded(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Guid packageGuid)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider.ServiceProviderExtensionMethods.EnsureSccAndTfPackagesLoaded(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider.Repositories.GitTeamProjectExtendedInfoProvider.set_ServiceProvider(IServiceProvider value)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamExplorer.ConnectPage.ConnectPageVS.Initialize(Object sender, PageInitializeEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.Framework.TeamExplorerPageHost.Initialize(TeamExplorerPageContext context)
```

Comment: Verify that the latest update is installed (update 1) and be more specific about how visual studio crashes

Comment: I don't know how I can be more specific because it is crashing when trying to connect Team Foundation Server.

Comment: post the crash screen capture would be ok. and verify the version of TFS server that is being used and the update level of visual studio 2013 (update 1 or 2).

Comment: Maybe this edit is ok :) VS Update 2

Answer (score 5):

I have fixed it with these steps;

Clean the Cache folder on client computer. The folder path is: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache.`

Clean the Cache folder on Server machine. The folder path is: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Team Foundation\Web Access\Cache_v11.0`

After cleaned, on Server machine, click Start and select Run… to open the dialog box, then input `iisreset.exe` and click OK, wait it run completely.

Comment: This helped me when Visual Studio was freezing whenever try to shelve files to TFS. Now, Visual studio again goes busy(freezes sometime) and does nothing whenever I try to add work item before checking-in!

Comment: IT worked for the first time and then the problem returned. After some spelunking using procmon, I found out that the Git extension was faulting. so started devenv in safe mode and uninstalled the extension as well.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are have a corrupted install of Visual Studio. You can try to 'repair' it from "Add/Remove Programs". If that does not work you are likely going to have to Uninstall and re-install.

You should get the latest binaries from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42666 o9r MSDN.

Comment: I have this problem and neither a repair nor an uninstall/reinstall fixes it - I write this to save anyone the trouble

Answer (score 0):

I needed to delete my temp directory

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp