# Visual Studio Pro 13 freezes while using TFS add work item

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

When i try to add 'work item by id'it does nothing and vs goes busy!!

[image]

Whenever i try to check-in file in TFS. VS freezes and it doesn't give me any error message to work with.  I have tried following [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23587666/visual-studio-crashing-when-checking-in). 
It worked for shelve set but the problem persists when i try to associate work item. So, bascially, I can't check in my code on the team project.

Also, I cannot create a new query from "Work Items" in Team Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled all the software was under the Microsoft Corporation. 
Then I installed Visual Studio Premium 13. It worked.

Tell me how it worked!

*[edit Dec14- it the problem resurfaced after first check-in]*

These are some troubleshoot that worked for most guys but not for me:
[first](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/856fb12b-625e-4d59-a19b-abd58658cca2/visual-studio-freezes-when-trying-to-edit-a-workspace?forum=tfsgeneral),[second](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7e744c05-005e-4cef-8cbf-44a57c7d46c5/team-explorer-freezes?forum=tfsgeneral),[third](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ca9d729c-f39e-4629-9a82-4ec3e5fa7899/vs-2010-freeze-on-build?forum=vssetup)

**I re-installed VS 2012 Premium and it works like a magic!**