# Visual Studio 2013 Crashing When Opening Team Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

After opening Visual Studio 2013 successfully, I switch to the Team Explorer tab and consistently get a popup error dialog saying that, "Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 has stopped working" and "Windows is checking for a solution to the problem".

This seems to be directly related to TFS (2013 Update 4) since other tools that access TFS (like Source Control Explorer > Workspaces...) also cause the crash.

*Edit:* I have already tried a VS 2013 Repair. This took all morning with no different results.

This is frustrating because I cannot use TFS outside of the command-line tools. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate question, please check these submissions:                    

1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23587666/visual-studio-crashing-when-checking-in   

2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883371/visual-studio-2010-crashes-on-startup

Comment: I have found a solution to this. This is similar to the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23587666/visual-studio-crashing-when-checking-in. Credit to https://stackoverflow.com/users/2121065/tu%c4%9frul-emre-atalay.

Answer (score 4):

Credit to [Tuğrul Emre Atalay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2121065/tu%C4%9Frul-emre-atalay) for the post: [Visual Studio Crashing When Checking In](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23587666/visual-studio-crashing-when-checking-in).

His issue was checking in changes and having Visual Studio crash. In my case, just using the TFS tools was consistently causing a crash.

The fix for me was to only clear out the local cache and **not** both the server and local caches.

> Clean the Cache folder on client computer. The folder path is: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache.

I cleared this folder and I was able to use all of the TFS tools without any further issues.

I then realized that this happened since migrating to a new user name. I had copied many of my settings over from my old account folder and it must have corrupted the cache area.

Comment: In my case, the crashes occurred after I had renamed the PC (inside a virtual machine) and had tried to clear up the resulting workspace mess with `tf workspaces /updateComputerName" and a subsequent workspace rename. For some reason, after the next program launch VS2013 believed that the old workspace should still be on the machine, and decided to crash after it was unable to find it. Clearing the cache folder fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with Visual Studio 2015 Enterprises. When i open it, VS wasn't able to connect to TFS and it crashed when i clicked on "manage connections"

The issue was not about the cache (I cleared the cache, made a repair of VS and nothing changed) but about the fact that we are currently migrating our projects from perforce to Git with Team Foundation Server.

When Visual Studio starts, it seems VS is trying to connect to TFS with linked Git repositories, but since the plugin currently used is perforce, it causes an exception somehow.

**The solution is to set your source control plugin to Microsoft Git Provider (or Visual Studio Team Foundation Server if you are using it)**

Here's two screen shots I took. Right after I selected the Microsoft Git Provider, the Team Explorer tab automatically refreshed and I am now able to connect to my projects.

[image: git]
[image: perforce]

Comment: Hello, that worked for me on vs 2017, but first I reseted settings to default  devenv.exe /resetsettings

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools -> Extensions and Updates 
 Look for  **Github Extension for Visual Studio**  and  **Uninstall it** 
Never Mind as you can still work with Github
Now Restart Visual Studio.
Enjoy working on Team Explorer.